# I am trying to load a jsp using spring boot with gradle but I am only getting internal server error

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, tomcat, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am new to spring boot and trying to load a jsp page but even after trying a lot and searching on internet I couldn't find any solution of it. I am unable to get  the error causing part in this complete process.

To build this all I used command 'gradle build' on command prompt.

To start the server I used command :- java -jar build\libs\one-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

then I on browser I typed :- http://localhost:8080/helloWorld

Here is my build.gradle

```js
plugins {
 id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
 id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
 id 'java'
 id 'war'
}

group = 'com.tm'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
 developmentOnly
 runtimeClasspath {
  extendsFrom developmentOnly
 }
}

repositories {
 mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  providedRuntime 'javax.servlet:jstl'
  providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
 developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

 testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
  exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
 }
}

test {
 useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This is my java code of controller HelloJSPController.java, it is in this folder structure: \src\main\java\com\tm\one

```
package com.tm.one;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
@Controller
public class HelloJSPController 
{
 @GetMapping("/helloWorld")
 public String helloWorld()  
  {
    return "helloWorld";
  }
}
```

This is WebMvcConfig.java configuration file

```
package com.tm.one.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
 @Bean
 public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() 
  {
     InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
     resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
     resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
     return resolver;
  }

 }
```

OR I tried this two lines in application.propertes also instead of above configuration file

> spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
>     spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

This is JSP file helloWorld.jsp in folder structure :--  \one\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello everyone I am AD</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This is error I am getting on browser

```html
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jan 13 16:53:14 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [helloWorld], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

This is OneApplication.java

```
package com.tm.one;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;     
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;  

@SpringBootApplication


    public class OneApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(OneApplication.class, args);
        }


    @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(OneApplication.class);
        }


    }
```

Comment: What is the filename of your .jsp file?

Comment: name of jsp file is helloWorld.jsp

Comment: be aware that there are limitations with JSP support when using embedded containers in Springboot: see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations  . did you try to generate and use WAR instead of JAR, as suggested  in the doc?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti  I initially had jar packaging but later I converted it to war by putting "id 'war' " in build.gradle and extending  SpringBootServletInitializer in OneApplication class . BUT still it is not working unable to load jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue as you, and I believe it's not because of the code. The only solution I found was switching to `maven`. Absolutely no other change in the java code, only `build.gradle` -> `pom.xml`.